# Despite the JSON.stringify, my console.log return [object Object]

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, constants, return-value

I am coming to you because I am launching into javascript and I am doing an exercise. I need to get the "first" and "last" out of an array, I messed around a bit and I think I'm on the right track. But when I look in the console I see [object Object]. I put the "JSON.stringify" and it still does the same to me.

Here is my code:

```js
const entrepreneurs = [
    { first: 'Steve', last: 'Jobs', year: 1955 },
    { first: 'Oprah', last: 'Winfrey', year: 1954 },
    { first: 'Bill', last: 'Gates', year: 1955 },
    { first: 'Sheryl', last: 'Sandberg', year: 1969 },
    { first: 'Mark', last: 'Zuckerberg', year: 1984 },
    { first: 'Beyonce', last: 'Knowles', year: 1981 },
    { first: 'Jeff', last: 'Bezos', year: 1964 },
    { first: 'Diane', last: 'Hendricks', year: 1947 },
    { first: 'Elon', last: 'Musk', year: 1971 },
    { first: 'Marissa', last: 'Mayer', year: 1975 },
    { first: 'Walt', last: 'Disney', year: 1901 },
    { first: 'Larry', last: 'Page', year: 1973 },
    { first: 'Jack', last: 'Dorsey', year: 1976 },
    { first: 'Evan', last: 'Spiegel', year: 1990 },
    { first: 'Brian', last: 'Chesky', year: 1981 },
    { first: 'Travis', last: 'Kalanick', year: 1976 },
    { first: 'Marc', last: 'Andreessen', year: 1971 },
    { first: 'Peter', last: 'Thiel', year: 1967 }
  ];


  
// DATE

  function dateBetween(y)
  {
      return y.year > 1970 && y.year < 1980;
  }
  
  const resultYear = entrepreneurs.filter(dateBetween)


  
  {
    document.write("Liste de ceux nés dans les années 70 : " + "voir console je sais pas convertir");
}

console.log(resultYear)


// PRENOM ET NOM

const resultName = entrepreneurs.map(obj => {
    var rObj = {};
    rObj[obj.clé] = obj.first;
    var rObjd = {};
    rObjd[obj.clé] = obj.last;
    return rObjd + rObjd;
});
//const resultFirst = entrepreneurs.map(({ first}) => first);


console.log(JSON.stringify(resultName))
```

My result in the console :
[image]

Thanks in advance !

Comment: `rObjd` is an object, and your `resultName` function has `return rObjd + rObjd` - that is, adding the object to itself. That makes no sense, so JS tries to make sense of it by converting the object to a string, resulting in `[object Object][object Object]`. You seem to be really over-complicating `resultName`, surely you can just do `entrepreneurs.map(obj => obj.first + " " + obj.last)`?

Comment: Oh thanks ! Its work ! Indeed I had not seen that eye there, thank you very much for your answer!